# How to print a Fractional x without decimal point if and only if x is Integral?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell how to print a Fractional x without decimal point if and only if x is Integral? Please improve my code below:

```
printFrac :: (Show a, RealFrac a) => a -> IO ()
printFrac x = if x==fromIntegral (round x) then print (round x) else print x
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
printFrac :: (Show a, RealFrac a) => a -> IO ()
printFrac x
  | a == 0 = print b
  | otherwise = print x
  where (b, a) = properFraction x
```

Test:

```
λ> printFrac 1.0
1
λ> printFrac 1.1
1.1
λ> printFrac 1
1
```